# About the Integral $\int\arcsin\left(\sin^{2}x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

$$\int\arcsin\left(\sin^{2}x\right)dx$$
I am not able to find a closed form elementary solution for this, though I have no reason to believe it exists.

But trying out the Definite Integral as follows:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arcsin\left(\sin^{2}x\right)dx$$

Using the Series Expansion for $\arcsin(x)$:
$$\arcsin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}\ \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
$$\arcsin\left(\sin^{2}x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}\ \frac{\left(\sin x\right)^{4n+2}}{2n+1}$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}\left(2n+1\right)}\ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin x\right)^{4n+2}dx$$

We are aware of the closed form of the Integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin x\right)^{a}dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)}$$

$$I=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}\left(2n+1\right)}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\ $$

Wolfram Gives a Closed Form for the Summation in terms of Hypergeometric Function as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\ =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,_{4}F_{3}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right)$$
Hence,
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\,_{4}F_{3}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right)$$

I have seen some cases where these hypergeometric functions end up in terms of closed form expressions.

Well my question is:

1. Whether the Indefinite Integral has a solution.
2. Whether the Definite Integral has a Closed Form Solution.
3. Whether the Hypergeometric Series has a Closed Form, which will lead us directly to the Definite Integral.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I mentioned it in the end.

Comment: Some equivalent forms:\begin{align*}I&\stackrel{y=\sin x}=\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin y^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy\\&\,\,\,\,=\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^{\sqrt y}\frac{2yz}{\sqrt{1-y^2z^4}}\,dz\right]\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\\&\,\,\,\,=\int_0^1\ln\frac{\left(z^2\sqrt{1-z^4}+\sqrt{1-z^8}\right)^2}{1-z^4}\,\frac{dz}z\\&\,\,\,\stackrel{\rm IBP}=-4\int_0^1\frac{z\sqrt{1-z^4}}{\sqrt{1-z^8}}\ln z\,dz\\&\,\stackrel{w=z^4}=-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln w}{\sqrt w\sqrt{1+w}}\,dw\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your second question is **YES**:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \arcsin\left(\sin^2x\right) \, dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin y^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy \tag1 \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[\int_0^{\sqrt y} \frac{2yz}{\sqrt{1-y^2z^4}}\right] \, \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \tag2 \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[\int_{z^2}^1 \frac{2y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-z^4y^2}} \, dy\right] \, z \, dz \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \underbrace{\ln \left(z^2 + \sqrt{1+z^4}\right)}_{\equiv \operatorname{arsinh}z^2} \, \frac{dz}z \tag3\\
&= -4 \int_0^1 \frac{z \ln z}{\sqrt{1+z^4}} \, dz \tag4\\
&= - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln w}{\sqrt{1+w^2}} \, dw \tag5
\end{align*}$$

The last expression can be evaluated using [this antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+log%28w%29%2Fsqrt%281%2Bw%5E2%29), giving a closed form of

$$\boxed{\ln2\ln\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+\frac12\ln^2\left(1+\sqrt2\right) - \frac{\pi^2}{12} + \frac12 \Re \operatorname{Li}_2\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)}$$

---

- $(1)$ Substitute $y=\sin x$
- $(2)$ Convert $\arcsin y^2$ to an integral and interchange them
- $(3)$ The antiderivative turns out to be elementary and can be done with an Euler substitution
- $(4)$ Integrate by parts
- $(5)$ Substitute $w=z^2$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This indirectly gives the closed form for the hypergeometric series as well.

Comment: How do you evaluate the antiderivative?

Comment: @TymaGaidash That I do not know. WA's result is merely a stepping stone in addressing OP's second question. I'm not sure how one might discern the antiderivative without CAS's help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The hypergeometric series admits also a nice series representation. Recalling the recurrence relation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ and the *[Legendre' duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula)*
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2z)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)}&=\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)2^{1-4n}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(4n)}{\Gamma(2n)}\tag{$\to$ (1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(4n+1)2^{1-4n}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{(4n-1)!}{(2n-1)!}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{4n+1}}\frac{(4n+1)!}{(2n)!}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> The integral can be written as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{I}&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n+1)^2}\\
> &=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\frac{(4n+1)!}{(2n)!}\,\frac{1}{(n!)^2(2n+1)^2}\tag{$\to$ (2)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\binom{4n+1}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to convert $\Gamma\left(\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)$ to factorials.

Comment: @BlackEmperor: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)